# How to use “avoir l'impression que/de”?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, prépositions

I was wondering when to add *de* or *que* after “j'ai l'impression”.
If the subject remains the same, do we just add *de*? For example:

> J'ai l'impression d'avoir oublié quelque chose.

And can an adjective follow the “j'ai l'impression” construction?
What if I said “J'ai l'impression que tu es en colère”?

Simply, I was hoping for some clarification on how to use this expression in different contexts.

Answer (score 3):

If *“j’ai l’impression”* is followed by an infinitive, use ***de*** (or ***d’*** in front of a vowel or mute H):

- J’ai l’impression **d**’avoir oublié quelque chose → I feel like I forgot something
- Elle a l’impression **de** perdre son temps → She feels like she’s wasting her time
- Ça donne l’impression **de** flotter → It makes you feel like you’re floating in mid-air

If *“j’ai l’impression”* is followed by a conjugated verb, then use ***que*** (or ***qu’***):

- J’ai l’impression **que** ça ne va pas durer → I’m under the impression it won’t last long
- Avez-vous l’impression **qu**’il se mettra à pleuvoir bientôt ? → Do you think it’s going to be raining before long?
- On avait l’impression que tu ne reviendrais pas avant une semaine → We were under the impression you wouldn’t be back for a week

Concerning adjectives (or other types of words) used with the phrase, they would then define more precisely the type of impression felt. I’d say they would usually **preceed** the word *impression*, though.

- J’ai la persistante impression que l’on m’observe → I persistently feel someone is watching me
- J’avais toujours cette impression de d’être sur le point d’un grand changement → I always had this impression of standing on the verge of some great changes

---

Also take note of the very appropriate comments by [aCOSwt](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/17526/) below. I shall integrate them into the answer when I have more time.

Comment: Oui et +1 pour une règle qui servira la plupart du temps. Dans les faits, c'est un poil plus complexe car des constructions *impression que + infinitif* sont tout aussi légitimes. *J'ai l'impression que discuter ne sert à rien*... En fait, grammaticalement, tout dépendra de si on veut faire suivre *impression* par un complément (+de) ou par une complétive (+que).

Comment: Sur le propos du commentaire précédent : On peut souvent observer l'envie (inutile à mon opinion) de toujours respecter votre première consigne (de devant l'infinitif) et au lieu du suffisant *J'ai l'impression que discuter...* on entendra *J'ai l'impression **que de** discuter*...

Comment: Thanks for the great replies. I just wanted to confirm what I had mentioned in my question regarding the subject. In the examples given in your answer, the infinitive (and, thus, 'de') is used in sentences where the subject doesn't change. In those where 'que' is used, the subject is different i.e. do YOU think that IT will rain/I was under the impression that YOU weren't coming...' If the general rule is de+inf and que+conj. verb, is the application of those two rules dependent on the subject. For example, one can only use 'de+inf.' when the subject remains unchanged.

Comment: @ArmaanKapila I made several examples where the subject is either the same or different. It is not so much the subject change or remaining the same as the verb introduced that will trigger the use of **de** or **que** after. “It makes you feel like you're floating” → subject changes, but **de** is used. “She feels like she's wasting her time” → same person, but **de** as well.